# Commit to git with a different path?

Tags: git

Say I have a directory `/home/userX/whatever` structured:

```
./wrapper
./wrapper/folder_A
./wrapper/folder_A/file_1
./wrapper/folder_A/file_2
./wrapper/folder_B
./wrapper/folder_B/file_3
./wrapper/folder_B/file_4
```

I want to commit them into a git repo `/home/userX/somewhere/repo.git` with this structure inside the git tree:

```
./blah
./blah/folder_A
./blah/folder_A/file_1
./blah/folder_A/file_2
./blah/folder_B
./blah/folder_B/file_3
./blah/folder_B/file_4
```

WITHOUT having to copy or move those files 1~4 to another folder or having to touch the system privilege (the `userX` is not a sudoer).

Is it possible? Any illustration?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Which operating system?

Comment: `/whatever` is a working directory on the server that should never be changed. I want the changes in `/whatever` to be backuped into the git tree instantly (if a file is large it probably take long to copy). The reason to rewrite the structure is that there are still something in the git repo (for example there is already `./wrapper/someproject` in the git tree). My OS is probably UNIX, but it would be good if the solution is OS-free.

Comment: git cannot do that. git always copies the actual data into its own internal files in `.git`. So it's not possible. Also it sounds like you also want autocommit on save, which is a separate question (and has previously been covered on StackOverflow).

Comment: If you think about it this is **not physically possible** without special operating system support (like e.g. OS X offers with its Time Machine feature) because if git didn't copy the data, it would be overwritten by the user without any warning, and lost.

Comment: Maybe it's ok for git to copy to internal. What I mean is not to copy files from A to B and than commit B (and copy to git internal, so there is a double copy).

Comment: You need to find out which operating system is on the server. It's not that hard! Just Google it!

Comment: Committing in `/home/userX/somewhere` does not require `userX` to be root, so you're fine there. If I understand you correctly, you want to create a commit in the `somewhere` repository (presumably a bare repo) based off files in the `whatever` directory, without copying, except for the copying done internally by `git` as part of the committing process. You can use the plumbing command `git write-tree` to create the tree object with the desired structure, and `git commit-tree` to commit it. See the [git internals documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for details.

Comment: @user4815162342: you almost caught all my point. But I may need a bit more detailed hints to write such a script.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, it could be reinterpreted as "how can I commit to a bare repository without a clone" or "how can I add a file that is never in my workspace".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements aren’t what I’d call crystal clear around the
general file ownership area, but here are a few ways to do it;
hopefully you’ll find one that fits your actual need.

### Level 0—don’t do that

You can most probably talk yourself out of really needing to do this.
It’s never going to be as atomic as you’d like it to be, so spare
yourself the complexity.

If that fails…

### Level 1—hardlink

With most operating systems, you can cheat your way out by faking
duplication at a filesystem level.  You seem to refuse this because
root or sudo is needed, but it’s so much easier than anything else I
have to mention it for a start.

In the olden days you’d just have hardlinked your `whatever/wrapper`
directory to `cheat/blah`, but it seems deprecated enough by now that
my example will use a bind mount instead.

```bsh
git clone /home/userX/somewhere/repo.git level1
cd level1
mkdir blah
sudo mount --bind /home/userX/whatever/wrapper blah
git add blah
git commit
git push
sudo umount blah
```

In plain English: mount the files you want to commit in a place where
they make sense to git.  Then add, commit and push them to where you
want them stored.

### Level 2—no `cp`

You can spare a copy by hashing the files directly in a repository.

```bsh
git clone /home/userX/somewhere/repo.git level2
cd level2
for f in folder_A/file_1 folder_A/file_2 folder_B/file_3 folder_B/file_4
do
  sha=$(git hash-object -w /home/userX/whatever/wrapper/$f)
  git update-index --add --cacheinfo 644 $sha blah/$f
done
```

Then commit and push as usual:

```bsh
git commit
git push
```

Note that the `git hash-object -w` command (in addition to the `git
push`, obviously) is the one that copies the files around.

### Level 3—no clone

You can commit “directly” to a local bare repository, from the
outside.  The blob hashing part is the same as for level 2, only
without the clone.  Building the actual commit is going to be a bit
more tricky.

First, we’ll need to create an updated index, that references the new
files.  Since git doesn’t really have any
command to operate on an external tree (and we don’t want to depend
too much on the internals’ format), we’ll use a secondary index that
we’ll initially copy from the repository’s head.  Apart from that,
it’ll look similar to level 2.

```bsh
mkdir level3
cd level3
export GIT_DIR=/home/userX/somewhere/repo.git
export GIT_INDEX_FILE=hack
git read-tree HEAD
for f in folder_A/file_1 folder_A/file_2 folder_B/file_3 folder_B/file_4
do
  sha=$(git hash-object -w /home/userX/whatever/wrapper/$f)
  git update-index --add --cacheinfo 644 $sha blah/$f
done
tree=$(git write-tree)
```

Now you can create a commit object and update HEAD.

```bsh
parent=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
commit=$(git commit-tree -p $parent -m Your_message_here $tree)
git update-ref HEAD $commit $parent
```

Don’t forget to clean up behind you:

```bsh
rm hack
unset GIT_DIR GIT_INDEX_FILE
```

### Level 4—remotely

It’s possible to do all of this remotely, but as far as I know no git
plumbing command will help us.  `git send-pack` assumes a local
repository, which seems out of scope here.  So you’d need to write a
dedicated git protocol client.

### Closing thoughts

If you aim for serious portability with all this, you ought to:

- further investigate the `--path` option of `git hash-object`
- make sure you avoid naming collisions on the secondary index name

Answer (score 2):

Import what you want through a sideband index

```
loaded_tree=$(
    export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$PWD/.git/throwaway
    export GIT_DIR=$PWD/.git
    rm -f .git/throwaway

    export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/userX/whatever/wrapper
    cd $GIT_WORK_TREE

    git add folder_A folder_B  # add contents (relative to GIT_WORK_TREE)
    git add anything else      # . to repo, record locations ditto in index

    git write-tree             # make an honest tree of it
)
```

And load it where you want into a new branch

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
git read-tree --empty          # (wipe it because `--prefix=` merges)
git read-tree  $loaded_tree --prefix=blah/
git commit -m "You're done."
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible using [git internal commands](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects). Be careful of the following commands as these meddle with the files git uses to represent the file structure, if used incorrectly it could lead to corrupt or incorrect states.

This will follow only the creation of a single file, the rest would follow a similar process. All this commands are run from the `repo.git` folder mentioned, which is assumed to be a `--bare` repository:

```
> cd /home/userX/somewhere
```

The first step is to create the git object that will contain the file you want to commit. This command will create a compressed copy of your file in the git object storage. This copy is inevitable since it is the internal copy git needs to keep a version of your file:

```
> git hash-object -w /home/userX/whatever/wrapper/folder_A/file_1
cafebabe00000000000000000000000000000000
```

The printed hash is the object that was created to store `file_1`. The hash is of course fictitious since it depends on the actual contents of the file.

In order to create the subfolders where `file_1` is to be located you need to create a tree object for each subfolder level. Notice how the hash created is used in hand for the next subfolder tree:

```
> echo -e "100644 blob cafebabe00000000000000000000000000000000\tfile_1" | git mktree
1111face11111111111111111111111111111111

> echo -e "040000 tree 1111face11111111111111111111111111111111\tfolder_a" | git mktree
2222face22222222222222222222222222222222
```

This last hash is the one that will be added the the current tree. If working in a `--bare` repo we need to create first an clean index. This step can be skipped if you are working in a normal repository since there is an index file already, just make sure `git status` shows a clean state.

In a `--bare` repo there should be no index file, but just in case there is, remove it:

```
> rm index
```

To create a clean index file we add the contents of the branch we want to commit towards, we will assume `master`. This command will print the contents of the current tree existing as `master` and set it as the current index:

```
> git cat-file -p master^{tree} | git update-index --index-info
```

Now with a clean index, we add the subdirectory containing the tree that leads to the file that we added manually. `read-tree` will take the given tree hash and add it to the current index as a subfolder named as stated in `--prefix`:

```
> git read-tree --prefix=blah 2222face22222222222222222222222222222222
```

And then we create yet another tree that stands for the current state of the index. `write-tree` will read from the current index and generate a tree hash out of it:

```
> git write-tree
deadbeafaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

This last hash is the one that we will use to create the commit:

```
> echo "at last a commit" | git commit-tree deadbeafaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -p master
baddcafe11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Last but not least we update `master` to point to the new commit:

```
> git branch --force master baddcafe11111111111111111111111111111111
```

And with that we managed to add into git a file without having to copy it to the workspace. All this steps is what `git add` and `git commit` end up doing. To replicate them through the git internal commands ends up being a lot of work and it is easily prone to accidents. If you really need to do this thread with care and understand the the underlying structure that git handles for you so that you can play with it and modify it.

Comment: What if I want to "git add ./wrapper/folder_A/file_2" after "./wrapper/folder_A/file_1" has been added? Do I have to recreate the file_1, the folder_a tree, and make a new commit tree?

Comment: You would need to follow a similar process to the tree creation for index. The difference lays in that for `file_1` there was just a single item in the folder and parent folder, and it was a new one. If you need to add items to an existing tree you need to pull that tree, add to it, make sure its properly ordered (which is what `update-index` handles) and then regenerate the tree hash of that folder and upwards to the repository root.